# Filtering my objects out of my array gives an empty array

Tags: php, arrays

this is my function where i firstly use ophalencontact()
to retrieve contactperson from my DB afterwards after these are put in my class i put them in an array(because 1 "klant"can have multiple contact persons)

now i want to put my contact person into my "klant(customer)" with a filtering method

```
$contact= array();
foreach($contactlijst as $CT ){
    if($key['idklanten']==$CT->getklantID()){
        array_push($contact,$CT);
    }
    else{$contact="";}
}
```

I think the fault could be in this function could anybody help me? the code does not get debug errors but when i render it on the website it gives me an empty array.

thanks in advance.

```
function ophalen(){
    $this->ophalencontact();
    $dbh = new pdo( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nextlead_spreker','nextlead_spreker', 'xxxxxx',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    try {$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from klanten;");
        $sth->execute();
        $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $lijst =array();


        foreach($row as $key){
            $contact= array();
            foreach($contactlijst as $CT ){
                if($key['idklanten']==$CT->getklantID()){
                    array_push($contact,$CT);
                }
                else{$contact="";}
            }
            $I= new Klanten($key['idklanten'],$key['naam'],$key['adres'],$key['postcode'],$key['stad'],$contact);
            array_push($lijst,$I); 


        }
        return $lijst;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        print_r($ex);
        die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
    }  
}

function ophalencontact(){
    $dbh = new pdo( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nextlead_spreker',      'nextlead_spreker', 'xxxxxxx',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    try {$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from contactpersoonklant;");
        $sth->execute();
        $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $contactlijst =array();

        foreach($row as $key){
            $CT= new klantContact($key['idcontactpersoonklant'],$key['Voornaam'],$key['tussenvoegsel'],$key['achternaam'],$key['tel'],$key['email'],$key['klanten_idklanten']);
            array_push($contactlijst,$CT); 
            print_r($contactlijst);
        }
        return $contactlijst;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        print_r($ex);
        die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of

```
else {$contact = "";}
```

You're adding all the matching elements to the array, but every time you encounter a non-matching element you replace the array with an empty string. You should just ignore the non-matching elements.

Another problem: You're never setting `$contactlijst` in the `ophalen` function, so the `foreach($contactlist as $CT)` loop isn't doing anything (if you enable error reporting, you should get a notice about the undefined variable). You return it from `$this->ophalencontact`, but `ophalen` doesn't do anything with the return value. So the first line should be:

```
$contactlijst = $this->ophalencontact();
```

Comment: i just added it afterwards still doesnt work if i delete it :( also there arent any non matching elements right now so this really aint the issue

Comment: Can you add the values of `$row` and `$key['idklanten']` to the question?

Comment: $ row as $ key are just a way to get all my variables out of my DB either way the ID is 1000 and in the link both of the contact persons are also 1000 on klanten_idklanten

Comment: See my additional answer.

Comment: how do you mean in the previous question? i thought u were refering to the values themselves

Comment: I wanted to see the contents of the variables so I could see if they really matched. I was a little confused about your code until I reformatted.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $contact to an empty string here:

```
else{$contact="";}
```

What are you trying to do in that else?